# How to show iad or admob in the whole view

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad

i did a game in IOS mobiles, and i add iAd and when it fails ad-mob will be shown. in my game there is a function called `GameOver` Whenever the user loss this function will be called. Now what i want is how i can add advertisement in the whole view when the user loss the advertisement in the whole view will be shown.

As you can see in app-store, there are games when the user loss, a view popup and it contain an advertisement and a video. I tried to do it, but the only thing that I'm getting is a small banner for iAd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this for full view

```
- (void)createAndLoadInterstitial
{
 self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
 self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 self.interstitial.delegate = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[
@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
];
[self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
}



#pragma mark GADInterstitialDelegate implementation

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial{
 NSLog(@"interstitialDidDismissScreen");
 //do you work
}
```

and framework - 
 GoogleMobileAds

Answer (score 1):

Full screen is known as Interstitial ad.

For showing interstitial ad in Admob:-

1. Create an adUnitID from [Admob](https://www.google.com/admob/), select Interstitial ad in ad type.

   ```
   - (void)createAndLoadInterstitial
   {
       self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
       self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID";
       self.interstitial.delegate = self;

       GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
       request.testDevices = ARRAY_OF_TEST_DEVICE_ID;
       [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
   }
   ```
2. iAd currently provides full screen ad only for iPad. If you app is running in iPhone there is no any way to show full screen ad via iAd.

[Apple's doc for full screen iAd](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html)